# What is an alternative for mysqli_fetch_all on shared hosting?

Tags: php, mysqli

`mysqli_fetch_all` is not working.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","file_upload");
$sql= "SELECT * FROM files";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$files = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Why is it not working? Are you using some old PHP version?

Comment: All you need is simply go to the host configuration panel, choose PHP modules and tick one named php_mysqlnd or something like that. mysqli_fetch_all **does** work, only some lazy providers do not enable it by default

Answer (score 1):

May this be of any help - using PDO.

```php
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;";
$conn = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, null);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM files";
$rs = $conn->query($sql);
$files = $rs->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```